# Sendgrid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails through using sendgrid template. But still sent, standard template.

```
def send_test_email(user)
    @user = user
    sendgrid_unique_args "filters" => {
                           templates" => {
                             "settings" => {
                               "enable" => 1,
                                "template_id" => "5e4a1ef6-a948-455f-b194-cec87ef88b0e"
                                  }
                                }
                              }

        mail( :to => @user.email,
              :subject => 'Thanks for signing up for our amazing app' )
end
```

After sending

```
  Sent mail to  test@ya.net (699.1ms)
    Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 10:00:04 +0300
    From: example@example.com
    To: test@ya.net
    Message-ID: <55cc407412764_23922fba2642131f@Vlad.mail>
    Subject: Thanks for signing up for our amazing app
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/html;
     charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    X-SMTPAPI: {"unique_args": {"filters": {"templates": {"settings":
     {"enable":1,"template_id": "5e4a1ef6-a948-455f-b194-cec87ef88b0e"}}}}}

<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thanks for signing up, Jovani!</h1>
<p>Thanks for joining and have a great day! Now sign in and do
  awesome things!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make that poisoned sendgrid template?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not clearly state the problem, but one thing I did notice is that your HTML does not have <%body%> which send grid needs in order to work with templates properly.